# call by reference basic example result

Tags: pass-by-reference

i am learning the basics.In this basic simple, if a,b are call by reference then what is the result ?

```
10 25
10 25
```

or

```
 10 25
 10 15
```

Code :

```
function sub(int a, int b)
        begin
            print a,b;
        end
function main
        begin
            int i := 10;
            int j := 15;
            sub(i,i+j);
            print i,j;
        end
```

Answer (score 0):

10 25
10 15

In this case it makes no difference whether it's pass by reference or by value.

The Sub makes no changes to the variables, it just prints them.

Answer (score 0):

Passing a variabile by reference means that inside the function you can change the variable value and outside you will have the value changed because you are passing to function its reference( the pointer to memory) and not its value. When you pass a variable by value the variable is copy inside the function so outside you have no effect

In you case the result will be

10 25
 10 15